# Recorrer array vue

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente array el cual trato de imprimir en consola de la siguiente manera

```
cargarColonias(idmpio){
            let vm=this;
            axios.get('/colonias-por-municipio',{params:{id_municipio:idmpio}})
            .then(function(response){
                vm.arr_colonias=response.data;
                vm.links=response.data;
                console.dir(vm.links); //Array que se imprime
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                toastr.error('Ocurrió un error al cargar Colonias.')
            });
        }
```

A mi me estan mandando estos datos, no conozco mucho como lo envian, pero debo de imprimir solo campo de nombre y de id. He intentado de las siguientes maneras:

```
console.dir(vm.links.nombre);
console.dir(vm.links->nombre);
console.dir(vm.links['nombre']);
```

Y hasta el momento ninguna me ha funcionado, ¿estoy realizando algo mal al momento de imprimir?

[image: Array]

Comment: Tendrías que iterar sobre el array. Puedes usar [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach)  `let array = response.data; array.forEach(element => console.log(element.nombre));`

Comment: Recomendación: tienes varias preguntas con respuestas de las cuales no has comentado  para recibir feedback de la *solución dada* o que hayas marcado como aceptadas, te recomiendo mejorar este punto

Comment: Gracias, me funciono para imprimirlos, pero si en vez de imprimirlos, quisiera mandarlo a otro array, seria de esta manera?

Comment: array.forEach(element => array_push(vm.links, element.nombre))

Comment: Y... la pregunta es "Recorrer Array: el cual trato de imprimir en consola de la siguiente manera". No sé que es eso de mandarlo a otro array. No conozco ese método `array_push`, dale una leída a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) para entender que son y cómo funcionan los arrays y cuáles son los métodos disponibles. Si sólo quieres asignar el array que te llega por ajax, hazlo como lo tienes en la pregunta `vm.links=response.data;`.